# collectionview cell is not visible even after delegate methods are getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionview` of size height 40. `UICollectionviewcell` of (25,25). Cells are not getting shown. every delegate method call is working fine.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
```

Comment: where is data source method?

Comment: @sagar I have implemented the data source method as well.

Comment: Have you confirmed delegate datasource to your view controller by dragging @AbhishekKashyap

Comment: add this UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout with delegate and datasorce

Comment: i think your numberOfcell conut retrun 0 , may it possibile.please send full code.

Comment: The flow layout delegate was not set, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class yourviewcontroller:UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

}
```

**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** add this

Comment: The flow layout delegate was not set, thanks for the help